# Arduino reads the same in potentiometer

Tags: arduino

This is the code I used

```
float vl0, vl1, vl2 =0;  // Variable para almacenar el voltaje
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Inicializamos la comunicación serial
}
void loop() {
  v0 = analogRead(A0);           // Leemos del pin A0 valor
  v1 = analogRead(A1);           // Leemos del pin A1 valor
  v2 = analogRead(A2);           // Leemos del pin A2 valor
  vl0 = (v0*5.00/1023.00);   // Calculamos el voltaje
  vl1 = (v1*5.00/1023.00);   // Calculamos el voltaje
  vl2 = (v2*5.00/1023.00);   // Calculamos el voltaje

  Serial.print(vl0);
  Serial.print("V");
  Serial.print ("/");
  Serial.print(vl1);
  Serial.print("V");
  Serial.print ("/");
  Serial.print(vl2);
  Serial.print("V");
  Serial.println ("/");


  delay(1000);
}
```

This is the output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN1fX.png)

As you can see it measures the same, and only alters when I move one potentiometer, Im new on this arduino thing.

I expected to yall can help me and give me some advices, I dont understand this language very well

Comment: And what is your problem? Can you measure the voltage at the pins A0 .. A2?

Comment: What is the voltage read on DMM? Kindly post the circuit connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this sketch until you manage to attach a pot to your pin A0

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Inicializamos la comunicación serial
}
void loop() {
  Serial.println(analogRead(A0));           // Leemos del pin A0 valor
  delay(500);
}
```